# $(...).tablesorter is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm having problems with the plugin tablesorter apparently my system is not identifying the function coo existing, do not know if it may be some conflict with other javascript (I'm making the change in a wordpress plugin).

Below is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
    $('table').tablesorter();
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

I changed the way i'm calling the js file

```
<?php
    wp_register_script( 'jquery.tablesorter.js', get_bloginfo('template_url').'/js/jquery.tablesorter.js' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery.tablesorter.js' );
?>
```

Comment: Are you sure the path to jquery.tablesorter.js is correct?

Comment: @JayBlanchard Yes, i can access the .js using source code from browser

Comment: Have a look in your network tab of your web developer tool, e.g. firebug. Are all ressources correctly loaded?

Comment: @Simon Right, all resources load, jquery.tablesorter.js too, but isnt identifying the function

Comment: The error is saying that the file is not loaded. Are there any other errors on the page? If you put an alert inside of the JS file does it show up?

Comment: are you reloading jQuery somewhere else?

Comment: @epascarello Yes, i already tried to debug too, but didnt work too.

Comment: You have a problem with loading the JavaScript file. Look at the net tab of your debugger. Do a hard refresh. Do you get a 404 when the JS file is requested?

Comment: How and where are inserting the JS files. You should be using wp_enqueue_script and add jQuery as dependency when loading the tablesorter.

Comment: @adeneo Hmm, ok i will try it, wait a minute.

Comment: @adeneo still the same problem, maybe the file can be wrong and the function isnt table sorter? the file that i'm copy is the same from this URL: http://tablesorter.com/addons/pager/jquery.tablesorter.pager.js

Comment: OMG. i'm gotting the wrong script '-'

Comment: Are you using any specific column parsers for your columns?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the site which provided the download file provides a plugin with the same name as the plugin, just confusing me and downloaded the wrong file.