# Table Sorter : table.config.parsers[c] is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, html-table

I'm having trouble using the [tablesorter plugin](http://tablesorter.com/docs/), it seems he is not able to perform the function that sorts the table, someone help me, I'm two days trying to solve this problem.

Below the error

```
table.config.parsers[c] is undefined
```

Javascript:

```
<?php
    wp_register_script( 'jquery.tablesorter.js', get_bloginfo('template_url').'/js/jquery.tablesorter.js' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery.tablesorter.js' );
?>
```

Table Code:

```
<table class="widefat tablesorter">
    <thead>
        <th width "70%">
        <u>Login do usuário:</u>  guilherme | <u>Nome do usuário:</u>    <span style="font-size:10;"> (<a href="admin.php?page=manage-files-main&deletefolder=/home/httpd/vhosts/simmmers.com.br/httpdocs/wp-content/uploads/file_uploads/62"> Deletar pasta</a>) </span> 
        </th>
        <th></th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th width="20%">Category</th>
        <th width ="10%"></th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="change_cat1" value="addit" /> 
            <input type="hidden" name="file1" value="Indice de Confiança do Empresário Março-SC 2013.pdf.pdf" >
            <input type="hidden" name="changecat_user1" value="62"> 
            <img src="http://www.simmmers.com.br/wp-content/plugins/user-files/img/pdf.jpg" width="20" >   Indice de Confiança do Empresário Março-SC 2013.pdf
        </td>
        <td>
            <textarea name="notes1" rows=3 cols=30></textarea>
        </td>
        <td>25/03/2013</td>
        <td>Indicadores</td>
        <td align="right">
            <form method="post" action="/wp-admin/admin.php?page=manage-files-main">
            <a href="http://www.simmmers.com.br/wp-content/uploads/file_uploads/62/Indice de Confiança do Empresário Março-SC 2013.pdf.pdf" title="Download Indice de Confiança do Empresário Março-SC 2013.pdf.pdf">
            <img src="http://www.simmmers.com.br/wp-content/plugins/user-files/img/download.png"   alt="" width="20" height="20" /></a> |<input type="image" name="deletefile" value="62/Indice de Confiança do Empresário Março-SC 2013.pdf.pdf" title="Delete Indice de Confiança do Empresário Março-SC 2013.pdf.pdf" src="http://www.simmmers.com.br/wp-content/plugins/user-files/img/delete.png " alt="" width="20" height="20" /></form>    
        </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What plugin are you using? Can you post the complete or a better (with more info) code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588695/tablesorter-is-not-a-function

Comment: @demonofnight the plugin is Table Sorter, i put the link in the post.

Comment: Are you using any specific column parsers for your columns? How are you initializing the plugin? What is different about this question from your last? Why did you not mark your previous as answered when you solved the original problem?

Comment: @KevinB I Put the table code in the post, the other post is a different problem.

Comment: Where's your javascript?

Comment: That's PHP, but i guess it's also useful.

Comment: It works for me using your html: http://jsfiddle.net/P73pe/

Answer (score 3):

I know it's a little late for an answer, but I've found that, if the table is empty (likely due to a PHP query that yielded zero rows from db) this error is triggered.

You can use a simple approach: if the table is empty, remove the `data-sort="table"` attribute from the table tag. That way, if your JS code is like this:

```
    $("[data-sort=table]").tablesorter({
      sortList: [[0,0]]
    });
```

you can be sure it will avoid all the empty tables, leaving you with just the populated ones ready to be sorted.

Comment: this was the solution for me too, I was getting the error: Object.r.storage Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'config')

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had some rows that had colspans in them (kind of like subheader rows) and tablesorter would throw exceptions on those.